# Warning C4701 is sometimes suppressed when compiling with /RTC1

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-bug, cl

This piece of code (note the commented line):

```
#include <malloc.h>

#pragma warning(error: 4701)

int main(){
    char buffer[1024];
    //buffer[0] = 0;

    void *p;
    int size = 1;
    if (size < 2)
        p = malloc(size);
    free(p); // C4701
    return 0;
}
```

Gives the following warning (as expected):

```
f:\d\warning.cpp(13) : error C4701: potentially uninitialized local variable 'p' used
```

However, **when I uncomment the assignment** in `main()`, the warning is no longer given. I am compiling with `/RTC1` command line option to enable [run-time error checks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz.aspx):

```
cl.exe /RTC1 warning.cpp
```

I've tried the latest 64-bit versions of compilers from Visual C++ 2013 and 2015. Both are producing the same behaviour.

Question is: is this a compiler bug, or is there an explanation for this? Microsoft's documentation mentions that /RTC1 might give run-time error in places where C4701 is given, but it says nothing about the warning being suppressed.

**EDIT:** The puzzling part is that the warning disappears only when `buffer[0] = 0;` is not in comment.

Comment: Try adding the compiler option /W4 .   /W1 is default and you may need it to be higher. And/Or try /Wall .  Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx

Comment: I think it should raise a warning in both cases. Otherwise, something wrong is going on. I do not think that line will solve the existence problem not even decrease the probability of it.

Comment: No repro on VS 2010. I get an error for 4701 regardless of whether or not I compile with the `/RTC1` switch.

Comment: Use connect.microsoft.com to report issues like this, we can't fix this here.  I'd randomly guess they'll tell you that `p` is in fact initialized when you use /RTC1 so this is expected.  That's accurate enough, be sure to mention that this is not the behavior you prefer.

Comment: Maybe I've formulated it wrong: the warning is suppressed only when uncommenting the commented  assignment, in combination with /RTC1. Problem is, this assignment is totally unrelated to `p`!

Comment: Richard Critten, the `#pragma warning(error: 4701)` statement overrules the /W option for specified warning.

Comment: I've logged the issue on MS connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2356140/c-warning-c4701-is-sometimes-suppressed-when-compiling-with-rtc1

Answer (score 1):

There are many situations where something is sub-optimal, probably buggy or even undefined where the compiler has a very hard time detecting this. Thus, you should not rely on warnings (and/or runtime errors triggered by compiler instrumentation) to give you the complete truth.

Know that the compiler *may* warn when you do something stupid. It also *may* generate code to blow up at runtime when you do something stupid. Just never rely on that. It can't detect everything and you have to know the rules yourself.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with your comment. But the problem here is: the warning is suppressed in debug builds that developers use, and pops up in release builds that the build server makes.

Comment: @Georgy Pashkov That's not unexpected. It's fairly common for optimizations to expose new warnings/problems that don't show up in unoptimized builds.